# How can I remove a single overlay in Openlayers 3.3.0?

Tags: overlay, openlayers-3

I am creating overlays in my mapping application that I need to refresh every 5 seconds.  I am only having difficulties removing the stale overlay from my map using the code below.  The `map.removeOverlay` method does not seem to be working correctly.  The stacking of the overlays is visibly apparent after only a few iterations.

Using `map.getOVerlays().clear()` removes the stale overlay, however, this removes all overlays which is not desired.  Any assistance with this is appreciated.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
 $.ajaxSetup({ mimeType: "text/plain" });
  $.getJSON('json/DATA.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data.item, function(key, val) {
         var storeName = this.name;
         var storeLocation = this.location;
         var storeLatitude = this.latitude;
         var storeLongitude = this.longitude;
           $.each(val.tasks, function(i, j){
             var taskName = this.name;
             var taskState = this.state;
               if (taskState == "Open") {
                var taskGeometry = ol.proj.transform([storeLongitude,storeLatitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
                function createCircleOutOverlay(position) {
                var elem = document.createElement('div');
                elem.setAttribute('class', 'circleOut');

                return new ol.Overlay({
                    element: elem,
                    position: position,
                    positioning: 'center-center'
                });
            }
                var taskOverlay = createCircleOutOverlay(taskGeometry);
                map.removeOverlay(taskOverlay);
                map.addOverlay(taskOverlay);
                }
           });
      });
     });

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            var taskOverlay = createCircleOutOverlay(taskGeometry);
            map.removeOverlay(taskOverlay);
```

The problem is that you are trying to remove the new overlay and not the old one. You would have to store a reference to the overlay so that OpenLayers can remove it from the map. Something like:

```
var currentOverlay = null;
window.setInterval(function() {
 $.ajaxSetup({ mimeType: "text/plain" });
                // ...
                if (currentOverlay === null) {
                  map.removeOverlay(currentOverlay);
                }
                currentOverlay = createCircleOutOverlay(taskGeometry);
                map.addOverlay(currentOverlay);
               // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have many overlays to keep track of you can set a name for each.

```
    overlay.set('name', `unique value`)
```

Then in your handler, loop through until you find it/them

```
 map.getOverlays().forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.get('name') && (layer.get('name') == `unique value`)) {
                map.removeOverlay(layer)
                return // if each name has a unique name set
            }
        })
```